# Why does this algorithm work for Quadratic Probing?

Tags: algorithm, math, hash, hashtable, quadratic-probing

Why does incrementing offset by 2 make sense? I know this algorithm works, I have plotted the results resulting in a x^2 type graph but I just can't see it. Could someone explain it in simple terms? Thank you!

```
        size_t FindPos(const HashedObj & x) const {
        size_t offset = 1;
        size_t current_pos = InternalHash(x);

        while (array_[current_pos].info_ != EMPTY && array_[current_pos].element_ != x) {
           current_pos += offset;  
           offset += 2;
           if (current_pos >= array_.size())
              current_pos -= array_.size();
           }
       return current_pos;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing `offset` by `2` in every iteration, so after the `n`-th iteration if will have value `1+2*n`.

You are adding this to `current_pos` in each iteration. So in the first iteration you are adding `1+0*2` to `current_pos`, in the second you are adding `1+1*2`, in the third `1+2*2` and so on.

The total amount added to `current_pos` by the end of the `m`'th iteration of the body will therefore be the sum of `1+2*n` from `n=0` to `n=m-1`, neglecting the modulo operation for a moment.

Using linearity of addition, this sum can be written as `m + 2 * sum(n for n=0 to m-1)`. The remaining sum can be shown to evaluate to `m*(m-1)/2`, so that the total is

```
m + 2 * m*(m-1)/2 = m**2
```

So this method does the same as using `(current_pos + m**2) % array_.size()` in each iteration with `m` being the loop counter and without modifying `current_pos` would.

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes a lot more sense now.